# Google Vision - RPC deadline exceeded. Image processing error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision

We are using Google Vision API to extract text from image. Suddenly, since this morning, Google API returns the below error for few images and empty text(with HTTP 200 status code) for others.

> Status: 4, Message: image-annotator::RPC deadline exceeded.: Image
>   processing error!

Can someone explain why we are getting that error and how we can rectify it?

Comment: Sounds like network latency...

Comment: @Tienkamp - from when you are getting this error? was your service fine until yesterday?

Comment: mine is now back to normal